# Generic Typeguard

Tags: typescript, typeguards, type-narrowing

So at work we use these the types which create the base of of our Geometries:

```
export type GeoJSON = Geometry | Feature;

export type GeoJsonTypes = GeoJSON['type'];

export interface GeoJsonObject { type: GeoJsonTypes; }

export interface Point extends GeoJsonObject {
   type: 'Point';
   coordinates: number[];
 }

export interface MultiPoint extends GeoJsonObject {
   type: "MultiPoint",
   coordinates: number[][];
 }

export type Geometry =
 | Point
 | MultiPoint

export interface Feature<G extends Geometry = Geometry>
  extends GeoJsonObject {
  type: 'Feature';
  geometry: G;
}
```

The issue is that we end up having to create separate typeguard for each Geometry:

```
export const isPointGeometry = (g: Geometry): g is Point => {
  return (g as Point).type === 'Point';
};
```

I tried to create a generic typeguard by writing:

```
export function isGeometry<T extends Geometry, G extends GeoJsonObject['type']>(feature: T, geometry: G): feature is T {
  return feature && feature && feature.type === geometry;
}
```

But to no avail. as i still get an issue with? Anyone got an idea?

```
export function coordinatesFor(f: Feature<Point | MultiPoint>) {
  if (isGeometry(f.geometry, 'Point')) {
   return f.geometry.coordinates ?? []; // Expected Feature<Point> but got Feature<Point | MultiPoint>
  }
  return [];
 }
```

Comment: As long as the type auf feature (in you guard it is T) and the return type (in you guard it is T) you just proof the type is what it is. So you need to separate these types and you need to call the function with this type: isGeometry<Polygon>(...) BUT from my point of view is makes no sense. As you are unable to check the generic type you give into the function it is just nice code with less security. better would be to have one guard per type.

Comment: Please consider [edit]ing the code so it's a [mre] that demonstrates what you're talking about if someone copies and pastes it into a standalone IDE [without unrelated issues](//tsplay.dev/WzxpLN) (e.g., undeclared types, `feature && feature`, etc). That will let people get to work on it immediately and increase the chance you get good answers. Unless the question *depends* on geojson to make sense, the code should ideally not refer to it; could you either tag the question as depending on geojson, import the relevant types in the example, or even better: replace them with example types?

Comment: Thank you @jcalz i've updated with an example to a Playground, it's kinda hard to narrow down as it kinda dependends on the types, but hopefully it's minimal enough

Comment: I see you've linked to a playground, which is great. But you should also copy it into the question as plaintext for it to be a [mre]. Those are the SO rules (nobody should be required to navigate away from SO to see the example code).  I'd do it for you but I'd need explicit permission, since it's not clear than anyone but you has the right to copy externally hosted code (yes I know the code is base64 encoded in the URL, but legally it's not clear what counts as copying)

Comment: But: looking at the example now, my solution would look like the one already posted [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76395969/2887218), so that's the way to go.  (Still edit it in, pls, though)

Comment: @jcalz Ohh okay, I understand what u mean about Minimal Reproducible example now, I've updated the question, hope it's okay now :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this way:

```
function isGeometry<T extends Geometry, G extends T['type'] = Geometry['type']>(
  feature: T,
  geometry: G,
): feature is Extract<T, { type: G }> {
  return feature && feature && feature.type === geometry;
}
```

Here we do two things:

- We infer type `G` based on `T` argument in order to make sure, that `G` is always compatible with given `T` and make it impossible to call the function with wrong combination of arguments, such as: `isGeometry(somePoint, 'Polygon')`.
- With `Extract<T, { type: G }>` in return type we pick those `Geometry` union members, that are compatible to (the geometry we are looking for)`{ type: G }`.

Comment: [While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/300837/2887218)

Comment: Thank you it works, perfectly! Would you mind explaining how it works, i don't understand why i need `= Geometry['type']`?  I think i understand why we needed the `Extract<T, {type: G}>` It's basically cause we want to narrow the Geometry based on the   type, such as 'point' which is a unique identifier, thus always leaving us with a single option and that's what lets us actually narrow down and give us the typeguard needed.

Comment: @MartinHansson I used equality sign `= Geometry['type']` to make second argument(of generic) optional for the case, if we (for some reason) want to pass first argument explicitly. 

In our case there's no different whether we use `= Geometry['type']` or `= T['type']` for that, both will work the same way.

P.S I added explanation to the answer.