# Generic Typeguard for Inner type

Tags: typescript, geojson, typeguards, type-narrowing

so i've got some issues, at work we use these types:

```
export type GeoJSON = Geometry | Feature;

export type GeoJsonTypes = GeoJSON['type'];

export interface GeoJsonObject { type: GeoJsonTypes; }

export interface Point extends GeoJsonObject {
   type: 'Point';
   coordinates: number[];
 }

export interface MultiPoint extends GeoJsonObject {
   type: "MultiPoint",
   coordinates: number[][];
 }

export type Geometry =
 | Point
 | MultiPoint

export interface Feature<G extends Geometry = Geometry>
  extends GeoJsonObject {
  type: 'Feature';
  geometry: G;
}
```

The issue that we're having is that we end up having to create a Typeguard for each **Feature** at the callsites when we have `Feature<Geometry>` that we want to narrow.

```
export function isPolygon(f: Feature): f is Feature<Polygon> {
  return f && f.geometry && f.geometry.type === 'Polygon';
}
```

I want to make a generic typeguard, i used [Generic Typeguard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76395164/generic-typeguard) as base for my thinking but i'm stuck.

I know that i can use the `Extract<Geometry, {type: U}>` to get my type such as this example.

```
export function isFeature<T extends Feature<Geometry>, U extends T['geometry']['type']>(
  feature: T,
  type: U
): feature is Feature<Extract<Geometry, { type: U }>> {
  return feature && feature.geometry && feature.geometry.type === type;
}
```

The problem that i'm having is that if i constrain T to be of type Feature, i have no use for the T variable in the expression, it gives me an error saying `A type Predicate's type must be assignable to it's parameter type`, If i constrain it to Geometry, then i can't use `Feature<Extract<T, {type: U}>>` Cause `T could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated`, is there any way to have the generic typeguard for a feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that in the type guard you type `feature` as `T` and you are checking whether `feature` is something else other than `T`, which is logically impossible to convert `T` to `Feature<Extract<Geometry, { type: U }>>`. Instead, you should only accept `U` and keep the `feature` nongeneric, just `unknown`.

```
isFeature<U extends Feature<Geometry>["geometry"]["type"]>(
  feature: unknown,
  type: U
): feature is Feature<Extract<Geometry, { type: U }>> {}
```

This will cause many repetitive checks and to avoid them we can create a generic `isObject` type guard that would turn any object type `T` to `Partial<Record<keyof T, unknown>>`. The reason to turn properties to `unknown` and make the whole object partial is to make it as type-safe as possible:

```
const isObject = <T>(
  arg: unknown
): arg is Partial<Record<keyof T, unknown>> => {
  return !!arg && typeof arg === "object" && !Array.isArray(arg);
};
```

Next, we can extract a type guard for generic features, ideally you would also include the `geometry.coordinates` into checking:

```
const isFeatureBase = (arg: unknown): arg is Feature => {
  return (
    isObject<Feature>(arg) &&
    isObject<Feature["geometry"]>(arg.geometry) &&
    typeof arg.type === "string" &&
    typeof arg.geometry.type === "string"
  );
};
```

Finally, our `isFeature` will look like this:

```
function isFeature<U extends Feature<Geometry>["geometry"]["type"]>(
  feature: unknown,
  type: U
): feature is Feature<Extract<Geometry, { type: U }>> {
  return isFeatureBase(feature) && feature.geometry.type === type;
}
```

Usage:

```
const a = {};
if (isFeature(a, "MultiPoint")) {
  // "MultiPoint"
  a.geometry.type;
}
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ts=5.0.4#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcDiwICkDKB5AOTgF51MBbYGKROAHzgDFgBDGAVymAG4AoX0JFgJkqDNgDOEAHYAVURJJls+AgG0AREhQaAunwHho8AJbSYwKADMWAYzGYsU6XgBGAK2C34Ab15wRFAAuZScZeRQJPgBffkFjODMLaztUAAUIJLhQC2kAE0VxMJcPL19-QOAQjQykjT4A2whoPLM2YAkQ6XZyV0s1fV5YwyFTc0sbezgAWXYAGxgTWvNskFyC0Oc3T284PwDtKrgNWYWlzPN6iqaWtotOuG7e-t0BmLijYUPlSmpaUmW8AYp0WgIM8WESQmqSYrA4XAAPGhVutChQqDQlOJfjQAHwo4D5NGSGTbMp7CqHarMNicYBXAIAc3RfxCaHevCa0gkpgkZN2pARslxAAoKiwoIyQuxpABraQQADu0l4AEoQhLGYlFGkJYsWHMEQAlLwtBGy4CICBWOCyAA0cBl8qV0lx+OI+P2cC48OkcAAhP7NXAAGQhyrWuDB4gx44QUreDSh8P+gCCUCgLEQADoTBJ05nECLNaqYgYuTztTT4cAAEIsCSoUjFyXSuUK5XqqOS7Ww2lcEieio+zh+sUBAJ5-kwBHVumikvJiqTvkJmdzriaZkQHGIPQLyXZ7e71VLicRm2a7PfGOkDQ8qBmRlJsPLi-dxlHlk0a+iEix+9qCfDQKlLIZwU+eArBlbwTBkKs4TpBEAFUCSJPsayRb9EFxLdsL0TRDn3cc4CsRCuDbZ1lTtSlRBCZC1RCMj+1QPMMKQgBRNZM28LCdwxRAHR8Sp6LgaI3QpAIRygP08w3OsG2AEVmJrU8w1I8jgC-fi-l-FB-1IQ4OQreAWCUHxoj4EwbRFOTNOLB0TnmUELhgDRVVPL0WG03c9OACoAHoArgAA9AB+IZ+CAA)

Comment: Thank you so much it works! Let me see if i understand this, our IsObject is Checking if we're passing an object, and that it's not an array, i don't understand the !!arg what purpose does that serve? Finally our typeguard returns a Record of all the keys of T, mapped to unknown, but optional, since that will cover all keys, that might gets lost if we don't have it? 

The featureIsBase then uses the isObject Constrained to Feature, and passes the arg, 
The same goes for geometry, where we contrain to Feature['geometry'] and passes the args.geometry, finally we check that both type as string

Comment: we need `!!arg` since `typeof null === 'object'` is true, an array is also `object`, thus we check if the `arg` is not an array as well. We make optional and unknown because in `IsObject` we don't check properties for validness. What if they are missing or having incorrect type?

Comment: Ohhh okay, so basically that it not null and that it's not an array!

Btw i modified your example to not take unknown, but to take Feature,
`export function isFeature<U extends Feature<Geometry>["geometry"]["type"]>(
  feature: Feature,
  type: U
): feature is Feature<Extract<Geometry, { type: U }>> {
  return feature && feature.geometry && feature.geometry.type === type;
}`

This seems to work just fine, is there any downsides to this?

Comment: It won't work if you receive a `feature` from API, which you should validate first. You will have to write something like this: `isFeature(feature as Feature)`

Answer (score 1):

I ran across this issue myself, and wanted to share how to do this if you've already validated that the object is a Feature, you just want to narrow the geometry type:

```
function isFeature<T extends Feature["geometry"]["type"]>(
  feature: Feature,
  type: T,
): feature is Feature<Extract<Geometry, { type: T }>> {
  return feature.geometry.type === type;
}

if (isFeature(foo, "Polygon")) {/* narrows foo to Feature<Polygon> */}
```

This works with [@types/geojson](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/geojson).